# Find the trace of matrix $P^{2012}$

Tags: matrices

There exists a matrix $Q$ such that $PQP^T=N$,where $P=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 0 \\
    2 & 1 & 0\\
    0&0&1
  \end{bmatrix}$
Given $N$ is a diagonal matrix of the form $N=\text{diag}(n_1,n_2,n_3)$ where $n_1,n_2,n_3$ are three values of $n$ satisfying the equation $\det(P-nI)=0$,$n_1<n_2<n_3$
Find the trace of matrix $P^{2012}$.

---

My Attempt:
I found the $N$ matrix.$N=\begin{bmatrix}
    -1 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 0\\
    0&0&3
  \end{bmatrix}$
I found the $P^2,P^3,P^4$.
$P^2=\begin{bmatrix}
    5 & 4 & 0\\
    4 & 5 & 0\\
    0&0&1
  \end{bmatrix},P^3=\begin{bmatrix}
    13 & 14 & 0\\
    14 & 13 & 0\\
    0&0&1
  \end{bmatrix},P^4=\begin{bmatrix}
    41 & 40 & 0\\
    40 & 41 & 0\\
    0&0&1
  \end{bmatrix}$
But i dont know how can i find $P^{2012}$.I cannot multiply $P$ 2012 times.Please help me .Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you write up the initial part correctly? What you want is a $Q$ such that $QPQ^{-1} = N$ (and here you are fortunate that you can do this in a way where $Q^{-1} = Q^T$).

Comment: I have correctly written the question.

Comment: Then the assignment has an error.

Comment: $3^{2012}+2$ is the answer given in the book.

Comment: And that is the correct answer, which is easy to see once the first part is corrected to what I wrote above.

Comment: I did not understand where have i done wrong?

Comment: If the assignment is as you have written here then you have not done anything wrong, the assignment simply starts with the wrong information necessary do solve it (also, I don't think the information at the beginning is even true, but I haven't checked).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

1. Trace of a matrix = sum of all eigen values of the matrix.
2. Eigen value of $P^k$ = $\lambda^k$, where $\lambda$ Is the eigen value of $P$.
3. We already have the eigen values $-1,1,3$ of $P$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT : given tr(AB)=tr(BA) try with $$N^{2012}$$

Comment: Can you elaborate this method,please?